# Azure search across 37 languages

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have a site which keeps English content and translated content (37 languages) in blob storage.  Each in their own folder structure in the blob.

Examples below:
Insider-progams/windows-insider/en-us/…bunch of json files to index
Insider-progams/windows-insider/ru-ru/…bunch of json files to index
Insider-progams/windows-insider/es-es/…bunch of json files to index
Insider-progams/windows-insider/fr-fr/…bunch of json files to index

We current have a .NET service which acts as an API to get this content and return it to our Angular web app.   However,  we are getting into scenarios where we need to search the content across all languages.

Does this mean we would need 37 separate indexes?  One for each language?  Or would we just pass a parameter to get the languages data we want from the API.

I am also concerned about how big an index might get and how long it would take the build.   We will need to rebuild the index on demand when new content arrives.

We also intend to use the Search APIs to for basic data retrieval of our content along with paging.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need one index for each language, only one *column* per language. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-language-support on how to create the index with different analyzers for each column/language.

[Indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#setting-up-blob-indexing) can automatically track the blobs in the storage account to periodically pick up new blobs and incrementally build the index without reprocessing everything.

There are a few options for populating the index depending on your requirements and use cases. The simplest option is to create one indexer per language, filtered by blob folder, targeting the corresponding column in the index. If you need more language capabilities or control structures, consider adding a [skillset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-defining-skillset) to the indexer which has the ability to [detect language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-language-detection), [translate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-text-translation), [extract key phrases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-keyphrases), [make decisions based on conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional), or plug in a [custom skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api). The last option is to manage [adding/updating/deleting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) documents in the index yourself, which has the lowest latency for any changes in the storage account to be reflected in the index.

See the [search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) for searching documents and paging results.

Comment: My JSON files are stored in different folders.  English in one folder,   French in another.   Etc.     For example, you would have one field called "content" in each JSON file.  You would have 37 JSON files.   Each JSON file having a translated string.   There isn't 37 content fields in one file itself so I am not sure the language analyzer would work in this case?   This is just an example of one page.   We have many pages each with their own JSON files x 37 for translated versions.

Comment: Or I suppose this could be 37 separate datasources.